# How to filter objects based on a string containing numbers in django

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a very simple filter method for my django app. Now I have a model Foo. Which has field area. This area field is a charfield.

```
class Foo(models.Model)
    name = charfield
    area = charfield
```

Now I want to search objects in foo based on area range. Let's say I have 10 foo objects having areas (1sqft, 100 ft, 3 sqft, 4sqft, 5sqft, 6sqft, 9sqft, 17sqft, 19sqft, 4sqft).

I want a query which will fetch me all the foos within the range 5-10. What is the best way to write this filter in django objects. Something like this:

```
Foo.objects.filter(area__contains = string(range(5-10)))
```

This is not correct but I want something like this. (Please comment if question is not clear.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to use range..more detail is here...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the area is a number it should be an IntegerField. Then `Foo.objects.filter(area__range=[5,10])` will work. You can add the units (square feet in this case) in your templates to save your users the job of inputting them every time and you the nightmare of keeping that consistent.